# call php function repeatly in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
function getTime()
    {

         var date = new Array(
        <?php
            $date1 = date("Y-m-d, H:i");
            echo "new Array(\"".$date1."\")";
        ?>);

        //document.write(date[0]);

        return date[0]; 

    }   
function showmychart() {

            max_time = getTime();
            min_time = getMintime(max_time);

            //document.write(max_time);
            //delete myChart;
            var c_channel = channel;
            myChart = new Drawchart(max_time, min_time,c_channel);
            myChart.showChart();

    }

    function changeSBS(){
        channel = 'sbs';
        showmychart();
    }
    function changeKBS2(){
        channel = 'kbs2';
        showmychart();
    }


    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <center>    
    <div id = "header">
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
                <input type = "button" id ="before" onclick="showBeforeChart();" value = "Before">
                <object id="chart"></object>
                <script class="code" id="Drawchart" type="text/javascript">showmychart();</script>
                <input type = "button" id ="after" onclick="showAfterChart();" value = "After">
    </div>
    <div id = "channel_position">
    <input type = "button" id ="before" onclick="changeSBS();" value = "aaa">
    <input type = "button" id ="before" onclick="changeKBS2();" value = "bbb">
```

in this code, when i click aaa button or bbb button I want to update max_time in function shomychart() using function getTime(). Now, when I click the button aaa, and bbb it doesn't update, i think it doesn't call getTime() function or   in the getTime() function doesn't work... How can i solve this problem????

Comment: In your Browser debugging tool, on the console, do you see any errors?

Comment: Just view generated HTML source. You gonna find what `getTime()` does

Comment: yeah, I couldn't find any error. Is there any error in my code? this is not my full code, just part of my code....

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4647853 - ask yourself is it what do you need?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski I am wondering whether the OP recognizes this as his own code...

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side language. This means that PHP code on your server is executed and sends the resulting plain HTML to your client's browser. When the browser receives your page, it will see something like:

```
function getTime() {
    var date = new Array(
        new Array("2013-01-01 13:37")
    );

    //document.write(date[0]);

    return date[0]; 
}
```

Note that the date is *baked* into the JavaScript code.

A better solution would be to use the *client's time* rather than (trying to use) the *server's time*. You can use JavaScript - which is a *client-side* language - to do that using a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object:

```
function getTime() {
    // Get current date
    var date = new Date();
    // Build a date string
    var dateString = date.getFullYear()
        + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1)
        + "-" + date.getDate()
        + " " + date.getHours()
        + ":" + date.getMinutes();
    // Return the constructed date string
    // wrapped inside an array (since apparently you need it in that format)
    // (Note that this is a short-hand notation for "new Array(dateString)")
    return [dateString];
}
```

Depending on what chart library you're using, you may be able to simply pass a `Date` object as `max_time` so you don't need to build a date string first. Then, just get rid of your own `getTime()` and simply use `new Date()`.

Comment: You need to understand how and where your code is executed. There are two very different parties involved in this: your server and the client's browser. Your server receives a request from the browser, executes your PHP and sends the resulting page back to the browser. The browser displays the page and executes any JavaScript code in it. The browser does not (and cannot) execute PHP code.

Comment: You can, however, write JavaScript code to initiate another request to your server (while staying on the same page) and use the response to update parts of your page. This is called Asynchronous JavaScript and XML (AJAX). It's very powerful, very popular and revolutionized the web by allowing developers to update page content without refreshing. In your case though, you simply need to get the current time which can be perfectly done on the client without a round-trip to your server.

Comment: Oh.. Thank u very much. I appreciate you answer